# How to see if a date is beween two other dates, and the time used and the time remaining?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

If I have set dates like Sunday Jan.29, 2012 2:00:00 PM and Friday Feb.3 2012 5:00:00 PM, 
and get the present time, how to I get the spent time from the first date and the present and how do I get the remaining time from the present and the future date?

I have code to show but it is all wrong. There has to be a easy way to do it that I just cant see.

Thank you

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use functions from [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

for example:

```
//get time difference between someDate and now
NSTimeInterval diff = [someDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

//get difference between dates
NSTimeInterval diff2 =[someDate timeIntervalSinceDate: otherDate];

//comparing dates
NSDate * earlierDate = [someDate earlierDate: otherDate];
NSDate * laterDate = [someDate laterDate: otherDate];
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I was almost there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dates available as `NSDate` objects, you can use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` to calculate the difference in seconds.

```
NSTimeInterval sinceThen = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

which will give you the time difference as an `NSTimeInterval` which is basically a double specifying the time in seconds. If the interval is negative, then `firstDate` is before now (which is the result of `[NSDate date]` otherwise it is in the future. If your date is not yet in `NSDate` form, you might employ an `NSDateFormatter` to do this ([See here, parsing date strings)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).